# Equivalent code of Mage::app()->getLocale()->storeTimeStamp() in Magento2

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

I would like to find out the magento2 equivalent of the below code from magento 1

`Mage::app()->getLocale()->storeTimeStamp()`

Can anyone assist me?

Answer (score 0):

Something like `\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface`?

For example:

```
protected $_timezone;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $timezone,
) {
    $this->_timezone = $timezone;
}
```

Then you can use:

```
$date = $this->timezone->formatDate();
```

Alternatively, `\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime::gmtDate();` might give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$dateTime = $objectManager->get("Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime");
var_dump($dateTime->gmtDate());
var_dump($dateTime->gmtTimestamp());
?>
```